# Можно ли изменить нативную тему приложений на Windows?

Tags: windows, native

Можно ли изменить нативную тему приложений на Windows? Я имею ввиду сделать так чтоб нативные приложения выглядели так как мне угодно, извините за глупый вопрос, недавно слез с arch + kde на windows и не понимаю как можно кастомизировать нативные приложения

Comment: Ну я темы для windows помню ещё с 95-й. Потом был популярен Rocket Dock. Тебе шашечки или ехать? Если тёмная тема нужна - ну в 10 вроде как завезли. Минимум для проводника - я видел.